# How to add default fonts to Django-TinyMCE

Tags: django, django-views, tinymce, tinymce-6

Like the title states.
There is no clear explanation in the django-tinymce documentation on how to add fonts, let alone set a standard font.
I use TinyMCE both in my admin as well as a view.

See the Documentation [here](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).